# custom fonts are not seeing after the build in Ionic2

Tags: angularjs, fonts, typescript, angular, ionic2

I am trying to add my own custom font files in **ionic2** application, added @font-face and path of my custom font-files.

**added it in app.variable.scss file.**

```
    @font-face {
      font-family: my-fonts; 
      src: url("../fonts/my-fonts.eot") format("eot");
      src: url("../fonts/my-fonts.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* IE6-IE8 */ url("../fonts/my-fonts.woff") format("woff"), /* Modern Browsers */ url("../fonts/my-fonts.ttf") format("truetype");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;

      /* IE9 Compat Modes */`enter code here`
      /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    }



$font-family-md-base: "my-fonts"; 
$font-family-ios-base: "my-fonts"; 
$font-family-wp-base: "my-fonts";
```

**Added in gulpfile.js :**

```
gulp.task("fonts", function () {
    return copyFonts({
        src: [
          "app/theme/fonts/**/*.+(eot|svg|ttf|woff)"
        ]
    });
});
```

When I build my application not able to see the this fonts in www/build/fonts folder itself.

Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you get a 404 in your console about the fonts missing? This seems like a path problem

Comment: Are you also adding the `fonts` task to the `build` task?

Comment: I set new task for custom fonts inside the gulp-file, But font folder itself is showing as missing inside www\build folder

Answer (score 3):

I just went through this and I just wanted to summarize what worked for me:

I downloaded Google Font Muli

Added this to the app.core.scss

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Muli"; 
  src: url("../fonts/Muli-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Add this to the app.variable.scss

```
$font-family-md-base: "Muli";
$font-family-ios-base: "Muli";
$font-family-wp-base: "Muli";
```

Added this to the gulp file:

```
gulp.task("customFonts", function () {
    return copyFonts({
        src: [
          "app/fonts/**/*.+(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)"
        ]
    });
});
```

Also add "customFonts" to the run sequence:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['clean'], function(done){
  runSequence(
    ['sass', 'html', 'fonts', 'customFonts', 'scripts'],
    function(){
      gulpWatch('app/**/*.scss', function(){ gulp.start('sass'); });
      gulpWatch('app/**/*.html', function(){ gulp.start('html'); });
      buildBrowserify({ watch: true }).on('end', done);
    }
  );
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function(done){
  runSequence(
    ['sass', 'html', 'fonts', 'customFonts', 'scripts'],
    function(){
      buildBrowserify({
        minify: isRelease,
        browserifyOptions: {
          debug: !isRelease
        },
        uglifyOptions: {
          mangle: false
        }
      }).on('end', done);
    }
  );
});
```

Stored the fonts in: app/fonts

Thanks for everyones help!!

UPDATE Ionic RC0:

You now just need to put in the following to your variable.scss file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Muli"; 
  src: url("../assets/fonts/Muli-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

$font-family-md-base: "Muli";
$font-family-ios-base: "Muli";
$font-family-wp-base: "Muli";
```

Comment: fontface we can add in app.variable.scss ryt?

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure. I put it in app.core.scss.

Answer (score 0):

I would change a few things related to the paths:

First, in the `font-face` rules, change the `src`

```
src: url("../fonts/my-fonts.eot") format("eot");
```

to include the `$font-path` variable like this:

```
src: url("#{$font-path}/my-fonts.eot") format("eot");
```

And then in the Gulp Task:

```
gulp.task("fonts", function () {
    return copyFonts({
        src: [
          "app/fonts/**/*.+(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)"
        ]
    });
});
```

By doing that, you should be able to find your fonts in the `www\fonts` folder.

Comment: How do I set src: url("#{$font-path}/my-fonts.eot") format("eot"); if my fonts inside app/fonts folder????

Comment: www\fonts or it should come inside www\build\fonts ??

Comment: Don't place your fonts in node_modules or build folder. node_modules folder gets update on npm install or npm update and build folder gets created with each build command. If you don't want to use the `$font-path` variable, you can also reference them like this:

`src: url("../../fonts/my-fonts.eot") format("eot"); `

Comment: Hey sebaferreras.. thanks for your support. but I got this issue solved, it in an other way. I was doing a mistake in my gulp file that, I didnt add the fonts in the gulp.task 'runSequence' correctly.

Comment: Great! If you don't mind, please edit the OP in order to include that information, so other users with the same issue could solve that easier :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this question.

Add a task for  custom fonts in the gulpfile.js to include the customem font files when we build the Ionic 2 application.

```
gulp.task("customFonts", function () {
     return copyFonts({
       src: [
           'app/fonts/**/*.+(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)'
       ]
     });
});
```

include the newly created task in the runSequesnce of **gulp.task('watch'**,  and **gulp.task('build',**

**runSequence( ['sass', 'html', 'fonts', 'customFonts', 'scripts'],**